# How to import private repositories on GAE SE Go 1.11, with go modules?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, go-modules

I have a go library package repository on github as a private repository.

And I wrote a project like below that import the library package above.

```
package main

import "github.com/foo/libpackage"

func main() {
  :
}
```

This is a directory hierarchy.

```
path/to/project
  |- main.go
  |- go.mod
  `- go.sum
```

When deploying I got a error that cannot

```
go: github.com/foo/libpackage@v0.0.0-20181127123728-008fddddc190: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/25a80f32a1edc8de002fe3d4532abdf933bba77505314d051e4b644faa9cabf6: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

It seems to get failed when go mod download.
I think it cause GAE does not be permitted to access a private repository(This is convincing)

Next I tried to run `go mod vendor` to download repositories into the vendor directory.

```
path/to/project
  |- vendor/...
  |- main.go
  |- go.mod
  `- go.sum
```

But I got a same error.

help!

Answer (score 1):

Send github credentials to go get:

```
git config credential.helper '!f() { sleep 1; echo "username=${GIT_USER}\npassword=${GIT_PASSWORD}"; }; f'

export GIT_USER=github_user
export GIT_PASSWORD=github_password_or_token

go get github.com/foo/libpackage
```

Comment: @junpayment How did you start the deployment that hit errors? With 'gcloud app deploy'? If so, try setting those credentials before running 'gcloud app deploy'.